# How can I perfectly add the text at the right of <input>

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to know I can I do like the below picture from google sign up form

[image]

I want to add "@myemail" in the right of input,and I know maybe I can use the structure like this:

```
<div>
   <input>
<div>
<div>
   <span>
<div>
```

and merge the two `div` in one line,but when I had done this,my border color can't match bwtween two `div`

especically I have shadow css in my code,there will be a line between two `div`,so I am really confused how to match two border color and shadow perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the one below. Just create a wrapper and style the wrapper with a border. Add an input with no border and outline also a span at the end.

If you want to add some border or some style when the user focus on the input you can make use of `:focus-within` pseudo-class. This will matches an element if the element or any of its descendants are focused. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```css
.input-container {
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.input-container input:focus,
.input-container input:active {
    outline: none;
}

.input-container input {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.input-container:focus-within {
  border: 2px solid rgb(114 76 252);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" />
    <span>@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,bro,it is exactly I want,thanks you very much!!!

Comment: @江俊辰 Have added some updates aswell.  Please have a check into it aswell. That will be really helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefplaceholder) attribute and style it

possible example

```css
input[type="email"]::placeholder{text-align:right}
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder="@mail.com">
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder
>
> The **`::placeholder`** CSS pseudo-element represents the placeholder text in an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element.

Comment: Thanks for reply,but I don't want the word disappear,I think I have got the answer already

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by floating the text of input to right

```
   input[type='text']{
   text-align:right;
    }

    input[type='text']:focus{
    text-align:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean tho. But I don't think placing a line of text floating to the right like that has any practical purpose beside asthetic purpose. If you want example of email, use `placeholder`. For pre-filled value so users can type less: use `value` attribute. If you want user use **exact** email provider, says `@gmail` and not `@yahoo`, use form validation.

```html
<input type="email" value="@gmail.com">
```